# Hotplug second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I use here a laptop with an extended screen sometimes.
First i needed to edit the configuration by Nvidia-settings to apply changes of my screen configuration, but now i have improved that by using Disper. That allows with one command to switch on/off the extended screen.

only single screen: disper -s ,
switch second screen on as extended screen: disper -e

Either i looking for a way to do this automatically. Is there something that can provide me a signal about hotplugging of screens? Something that is useful to trigger Disper?

Comment: Thank you for the reference to disper -- I'd never heard of it! Thanks to you half the headache of Ubuntu + Nvidia is relieved.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the binary nVidia driver provides this sort of functionality, and it would have to be provided by the driver.  I'm not familiar enough with the binary driver to rule this out, though.

The open-source nouveau drivers *do* send a signal on monitor hotplug, and that's caught by GNOME, so things *should* Just Work™ with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the option in the nvidia settings to save the changes to your xorg config file, then you won't need use a command. Every time you plug in an external monitor it will use the monitor in the config you chose.

Comment: Indeed, but this is not satisfying at all. When I use some programs with windows on both screens, it is needed to move these windows back to laptop screen before disconnecting the external monitor. This is automatically done when you switch to a single screen.